# Characterization of the unit disk

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

We know of a charcterization of spaces homeomorphic to [0,1], as being metric continua with 2 noncut points. We have as well a characterization of spaces homeomorphic to the unit circle. I can't find characterization of spaces homeomorphic to the unit disk. 
I'm using Willard's General Topology and Hocking and Young's Topology. 
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: When you start increasing the dimension, you will probably need some criteria which 'sees' that dimension. For instance the disc is the only compact $2$-dimensional manifold with boundary homeomorphic to the circle and trivial fundamental group.

Comment: See the answer posted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152223/characterization-of-the-unit-disk).